# How does this code extract the signature?

Tags: php, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I have to debug an old PHP script from a developer who has left the company. I understand the most part of the code, except the following function. My question: What does...

> if($seq == 0x03 || $seq == 0x30)

...mean in context of extracting the signature out of an X.509 certificate?

```
public function extractSignature($certPemString) {

    $bin = $this->ConvertPemToBinary($certPemString);

    if(empty($certPemString) || empty($bin))
    {
        return false;
    }    

    $bin = substr($bin,4);

    while(strlen($bin) > 1) 
    {            
        $seq = ord($bin[0]); 
        if($seq == 0x03 || $seq == 0x30) 
        {            
            $len = ord($bin[1]);
            $bytes = 0;

            if ($len & 0x80)
            {
                $bytes = ($len & 0x0f);
                $len = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $bytes; $i++)
                {
                    $len = ($len << 8) | ord($bin[$i + 2]);
                }
            }

            if($seq == 0x03)
            {
                return substr($bin,3 + $bytes, $len);
            }
            else 
            {
                $bin = substr($bin,2 + $bytes + $len);                  
            }                                                    
        }
        else 
        {                            
            return false;                
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You have a simple logical-sum in the condition.

Comment: Can anyone clarify on what the `<<` comparison operator does as well?

Comment: You understand the bitwise operations happening in the rest of the script but you don't understand the equality?

Comment: It seems that stackoverflow.com has some problem right now, I can't update the question. What I mean: What does the condition mean (the two values) in context of extracting the signature?

Comment: @Josh - '<<' is a bit-shift operator. "<< 8" means "shift left 8 bits". I can only spell PHP, so I'd guess they're using bit-shifting to "move" the first position of the string without substringing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An X.509 certificate contains data in multiple sections (called Tag-Length-Value triplets). Each section starts with a Tag byte, which indicates the data format of the section. You can see a list of these data types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**0x03** is the Tag byte for the [BIT STRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data type, and **0x30** is the Tag byte for the [SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data type.

So this code is designed to handle the BIT STRING and SEQUENCE data types. If you look at this part:

```
if($seq == 0x03)
{
    return substr($bin,3 + $bytes, $len);
}
else // $seq == 0x30
{
    $bin = substr($bin,2 + $bytes + $len);                  
}
```

you can see that the function is designed to skip over Sequences (0x30), until it finds a Bit String (0x03), at which point it returns the value of the Bit String.

You might be wondering why the magic number is **3** for *Bit String* and **2** for *Sequence*. That is because in a *Bit String*, the first value byte is a special extra field which indicates how many bits are unused in the last byte of the data. (For example, if you're sending 13 bits of data, it will take up 2 bytes = 16 bits, and the "*unused bits*" field will be 3.)

Next issue: the Length field. When the length of the Value is less than 128 bytes, the length is simply specified using a single byte (the most significant bit will be 0). If the length is 128 or greater, then the first length byte has bit 7 set, and the remaining 7 bits indicates how many following bytes contain the length (in big-endian order). More description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The parsing of the length field happens in this section of the code:

```
$len = ord($bin[1]);
$bytes = 0;

if ($len & 0x80)
{
    // length is greater than 127!
    $bytes = ($len & 0x0f);
    $len = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $bytes; $i++)
    {
         $len = ($len << 8) | ord($bin[$i + 2]);
    }
}
```

After that, `$bytes` contains the number of extra bytes used by the length field, and `$len` contains the length of the Value field (in bytes).

Did you spot the error in the code? Remember,

> If the length is 128 or greater, then the first length byte has bit 7
>   set, and the remaining **7 bits** indicates how many following bytes
>   contain the length.

but the code says `$bytes = ($len & 0x0f)`, which only takes the lower 4 bits of the byte! It should be:

```
$bytes = ($len & 0x7f);
```

Of course, this error is only a problem for *extremely* long messages: it will work fine as long as the length value will fit within 0x0f = 15 bytes, meaning the data has to be less than 256^15 bytes. That's about a trillion yottabytes, which ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: wow! what a great answer! You must be a genius, is your real name Albert Einstein? :-) Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

As Pateman says above, you just have a logical if, we're just checking if `$seq` is either 0x30 or 0x03.

I have a feeling you already know that though, so here goes. `$seq` is the first byte of the certificate, which is probably either the version of the certificate or the magic number to denote that the file is a certificate (also known as "I'm guessing this because 10:45 is no time to start reading RFCs").

In this case, we're comparing against 0x30 and 0x03. These numbers are expressed in hexadecimal (as is every number starting with 0x), which is base-16. This is just really a very convenient shorthand for binary, as each hex digit corresponds to exactly four binary bits. A quick table is this:

```
0 = 0000
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
...
...
E = 1110
F = 1111
```

Equally well, we could have said `if($seq == 3 || $seq == 48)`, but hex is just much easier to read and understand in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hazard a guess that it's a byte-order-independent check for version identifier '3' in an x.509 certificate.  See [RFC 1422](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1422), p7.  The rest is pulling the signature byte-by-byte.

Comment: ...except that the difference between 0x03 and 0x30 is not byte order, it is nibble order within the byte.

Comment: @Roland - a nibble is 4 bits, so it's the ordering of the nibbles in the byte. This is *very* rare and should never need to be checked for though. Endian-ness *could* be the issue here, but I couldn't say without seeing a full file-type spec.

Comment: @tcovo - exactly. Is the byte stored big-endian or little-endian in the binary representation of the PEM-format certificate? Either way, that code will find '3'.

Comment: @Roland-different hardware type may store the bits in a byte different ways. The "big-endian" hardware stores the high-order part of the byte (the most significant four bits) first, while "little-endian" hardware stores the least significant four bits first. historically, Intel (Windows) have been little-endian and Motorola (Apple) have been big-endian.

Answer (score 1):

[ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) gets the value of the ASCII character you pass it.  In this case it's checking to see if the ASCII character is either a 0 or end of text (according to this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Answer (score -1):

0x03 and 0x30 are hex values. Look that up and you'll have what $seq is matching to