# Parsing signature algorithm from certificate using openssl api

Tags: openssl, certificate

I am trying to parse [this certificate](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#308201173081BEA003020103020101300A06082A8648CE3D0403023000301E170D3134303631363232303030305A170D3139303631363232303030305A3000305A301406072A8648CE3D020106092B24030302080101070342000494FA7F32F5585DEC05EBA46C08593B794365E4198CAFD45FBAD502CAC538C3B69B30E666FB05FCDAFD23B93ECA16545559A3DB0F206247FFC48E921FA9B50406A328302630240603551D11041D301BA019060504007F0007A0100C0E3149534B30303030303030303031300A06082A8648CE3D040302034800304502204E4249273A4B7C2E615E6A58BEFF82D6337635B42AE30BFE15D383E48BAED22E02210099CF3B957BE7A0723B468EA4C8B9BB8BDE262A78F199BC716A8AA9E478BA63A0) using OpenSSL API and sig_alg is giving me trouble.

Entire certificate is supplied to OpenSSL library via PEM_read_bio_X509 call, however NID, SN and LN fields of cert->sig_alg->algor->algorithm are all NULL, while length is 8 and data points to 8 bytes which I presume hold the OID.

So my question is this. What function can I use to extract NID from OID?

I thought I could do it with `d2i_ASN1_OBJECT`, but I think this just copies the data aray to new or supplied asn1 object and does not interpret the data. And I do not believe that I have to construct my own list of well known OIDs like i think it was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627870/how-to-get-the-signature-algorithm-out-of-a-certificate) (not actually proficient in PHP).

On a side note, [this site](https://zakird.com/2013/10/13/certificate-parsing-with-openssl/) is instructing users to extract signature from cert->cert_info->key->algor->algorithm. I have tried to get the data from there but I have the same result. Some data in data, zeroes everywhere else. Also, is this information really on signature? Judging by the names there is information about the public key in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is this. What function can I use to extract NID from OID?

I believe the functions you are looking for are `OBJ_nid2obj`, `OBJ_obj2nid`, `OBJ_txt2nid` and friends. They can be found in `<openssl src dir>/crypto/objects/objects.h`.

The OpenSSL docs on them are located at [`OBJ_nid2obj(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OBJ_nid2obj.html).