# how to get the type of signature hash algorithm from certificate?

Tags: api, openssl, certificate

I'm using the OpenSSL API to get the type of signature hash algorithm from certificate.
For example, if the certificate uses the sha1, the api return sha1.
if the certificate uses sha256, the api return sha256.

but I don't know the api, please help me! thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing signature algorithm from certificate using openssl api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265893/parsing-signature-algorithm-from-certificate-using-openssl-api). Note the algorithm will be a NID like `md5WithRSA`, `sha1WithRSA`, `ripemd160WithRSA`, etc. You will have to break it out further into MD5, SHA1, SHA256, RIPEMD, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the API.
x509 is the certificate.

```
int mdnid=0;
if (OBJ_find_sigid_algs(OBJ_obj2nid(x509->sig_alg->algorithm), &mdnid, NULL)) {
                switch (mdnid) 
                {
                    case NID_sha1:
                        break;
                    case NID_sha256:
                        break;
                    case NID_sha512:
                        break;
                    case NID_sha224:
                        strcpy(hashAlgo,"SHA224");
                        break;
                    case NID_sha384:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }
```