# M2Crypto get certificate (X509) signature hash algorithm

Tags: python, hash, certificate, x509, m2crypto

For a small project I want to manage some certificates.
In the beginning I used the Python "cryptography" extension but I needed some further functionality so I switched to M2Crypto.

With "cryptography" I retrieved the signature hash algorithm from the certificate like so `cert.signature_hash_algorithm.name.upper()`. With M2Crypto I cannot find a way to get the same result.

How can I get the signature hash algorithm from a X509 certificate with M2Crypto?

Comment: DO you know how to do such thing with OpenSSL calls? (meaning in C)

Comment: Unfortunately not, only with `grep` but I fear this is not what you meant. `openssl x509 -text -noout -in test_cert.pem | grep "Signature Algorithm"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but neither a loaded certificate provides such functionality, nor does M2 offer an ANS.1 reader to manually find the OID of the signature to evaluate the hash algorithm from the signature.

```py
x509 = X509.load_cert_string(cert)
```

Sources:

- https://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.X509-module.html

Comment: Using the python cryptography extension I only did the following `from cryptography import x509; cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(string.encode('utf-8')); algo = cert.signature_hash_algorithm.name.upper()`. I was hoping this kind of functionality also exists in M2Crypto but as far as I can tell the value I want seems to be a computed value. Your code excerpt is how I create the x509 object. I was already trying to reach my goal with retrieving values from the public key but without success.

Comment: After further investigating programatically approaches I stumbled upon this snippet in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9745680/3978320 I haven't tried it myself but at least it seems there is a way to get the wanted value.